# Replacing the string value at specified place or index

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

AM having a text as

**Diagrams type: %s\nNon-standard Visio items will be converted as follows:\n\tShapes: %s\n\tConnectors: %s**

where as here i need to replace the 1st %s with **text1** and second %s with **text2** and 3rd %s with **text3** etc. 
Is it possible??if so how to do that ?

Comment: instead of %s, could you use {0}, {1} and {2} ?  If so, you can use String.Format.

Comment: `someText = someText.Replace("%s", "some text");`

Comment: @TimSchmelter i need to replace each %s with different string

Comment: @Vijay can you please tell how to do it.?

Comment: Read the `String` documentation, it lists what the methods do. If you read those and think about it, you might come to a solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are porting C++ code to C# you should use `string.Format()` and change your formatting string as suggested by Vijay.

Comment: @MatthewWatson am porting from VB to c#

Comment: @Arshad Ah, well the same answer applies then. That's really old VB code, I assume.

Answer (score 2):

You asked how to use String.Format in your comment.  Here is an example.  I'll update again in a few minutes if this isn't what you need.

```
string output = String.Format("Diagrams type: {0}\nNon-standard Visio items will be converted as follows:\n\tShapes: {1}\n\tConnectors: {2}", "SomeText 1", "Some More Text", "Even More Text");
```

That will replace each token ({N}) with each parameter in the supplied order.

If you need to keep your existing formatting for the string, you could use this approach:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\%s\b.*");
    string inputString = "Diagrams type: %s\nNon-standard Visio items will be converted as follows:\n\tShapes: %s\n\tConnectors: %s";

    int i = 0;
    string cSharpString = regex.Replace(inputString, match => { return String.Format("{{{0}}}", i++); });

string output = String.Format(cSharpString, "SomeText 1", "Some More Text", "Even More Text");
```

What that does is find all instances of `%s` and replace them with the C# format.  You then run the standard `String.Format` against the `cSharpString` variable and get your output.  All without changing the string you started with (in case you have no control over that string)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to loop around each occurance and replace each %s you find in turn using the `IndexOf` method:

```
string[] replacements = new string[] { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
string test = "Diagrams type: %s\nNon-standard Visio items will be converted as follows:\n\tShapes: %s\n\tConnectors: %s";

int index = test.IndexOf("%s");
int occurance = 0;
while(index != -1)
{
    //replace the occurance at index using substring
    test = test.Substring(0, index) + replacements[occurance] + test.Substring(index + 2);
    occurance++;
    index = test.IndexOf("%s");
}

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

I'm not sure where you have "text1" etc stored so I have put them in an array but you can use the `occurance` variable above to grab those values from anywhere you need.

**Edit**
@Rawling made a good point in the comments about the above being inefficient. I used the above for readability but with some simple changes we can remove the shlemiel the painter behaviour:

string[] replacements = new string[] { "a", "b", "test" };
    string test = "Diagrams type: %s\nNon-standard Visio items will be converted as follows:\n\tShapes: %s\n\tConnectors: %s";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

```
int index = test.IndexOf("%s");
int occurance = 0;
while (index != -1)
{
    result.Append(test.Substring(0, index));
    result.Append(replacements[occurance]);
    test = test.Substring(index + 2);

    occurance++;
    index = test.IndexOf("%s");
}

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

It's similar to the above but we are reducing the size of the `test` string to search for `%s` and then appending each section we find to a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: This is an example of a [*Shlemiel the painter* algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: @Rawling - I learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Rawling - you're absolutely right. But for a string of that length I'd go for readability over performance.

Comment: @Rawling - I've made an edit as I think your point is a good one.

Comment: You can also supply a start index to `IndexOf` to stop it searching from the beginning of the string each time.

Comment: I looked for that before I did the above and couldn't find it. That would be much easier! I should have tried it rather than try to find it on MSDN.